# E-d with infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I saw that:
\begin{align*}
N &>0\\
x &\to \infty \implies x > N \\
x &\to -\infty \implies x<N\\
\end{align*}
But
\begin{align*}
M &>0\\
f(x) &\to \infty \implies f(x) > M \\
f(x) &\to -\infty \implies f(x)<-M\\
\end{align*}
why isn't it
$$f(x) \to -\infty \implies f(x) < M$$
or
$$ x\to -\infty \implies x<-N$$
Do both work. If not/yes then why?

Comment: I guess it should be $x\to\infty \implies x<-N$. Though more context is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \to \infty \implies x \gt N $( here , $N\gt 0 $ is taken as sufficiently large.)
That means, as , $x \to \infty $ , so, however large, $N\gt 0 $ , we take , we must always have such $x\gt 0 $ that $x\gt N $

Whenever, $x \to -\infty \implies x \lt -N $( here , $N\gt 0 $ is taken as sufficiently large.)
That means, as , $x \to -\infty $ , so, however large, $N\gt 0 $ , we take , we must always have such $x\lt 0 $ that $x\lt -N $

Similar case also for $f(x)$ .